# How to add an exe file to the setup?

Tags: c#, desktop-application, setup-deployment

In my windows application, I need to install SQLLiteAdmin database while the desktop application is getting installed. How to do this? I'm using release mode. In the installer class, I used:

```
process.start(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\sqliteadmin.exe");
```

in after_install event. But, it is taking from the path `C:/windows/system32` and not from within the application folder.

Please, help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You meed to pass the TARGETDIR property from your installer to your custom action. [Enclosing it in double-quotes and added a backslash at the end.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w2fhwzz(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

if your executable is in your install directory try:

```
Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"\sqliteadmin.exe");
```